# xcode: should a segue point to tableView or navigationController?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a basic question: When I set a push segue to a `tableViewController` with embedded `UINavigationController`, to what of both I set the segue? To the `tableViewController` itself or the `UINavigationController`?

Is there any difference?

I am asking, as yesterday everything in my project where I am using `UITableView` with `UINavigationController` was fine. Today I open the project and the `UINavigationController` do not show up when I build and run the project.

When I go to the storyboard, I see the `UINavigationController` is still connected to its `UITableView`, but not showing the top `UINavigationBar`. First when I click the `UINavigationController` the top navbar appears again visible. But even with that the navigation bars are not shown in my running app...

Very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the navigationController - assuming you want to make use of him.